# Bijection for algebraic numbers

Tags: elementary-set-theory, functions, cardinals

Is there a bijective function $f(n)$, where $n \in \mathbb{N}$, which enumerates all algebraic numbers? Is it possible to define such function?

Comment: @GitGud:  that doesn't deal with each polynomial having a number of roots, some of them being the same, and different polynomials having the same roots.

Comment: @RossMillikan I had just realised that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**: Given an equation of the form $a_nx^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + \cdots + a_1x+a_0=0$, where each of the $a_i$ are integers, define the "index" of this equation to be $|a_n| + |a_{n-1}| + \cdots +|a_1|+|a_0|+n$.

We can count the algebraic numbers by counting the solutions of equations with "index" one. Then by counting the solutions of "index" two that we haven't already counted. An so on...

Comment: Unless I'm overlooking something, you're providing a hint to the proof that there is a bijection between the set of algebraic numbers and $\Bbb N$, but not actually a hint to how to find such a bijection. $\textbf{Edit:}$ I just noticed the OP also asked if there is such a bijection. I'll leave my comment here anyway so it's clear that this is a partial answer.

Comment: Can't one construct such a bijection by a bruteforce algorithm? Finding an explicit bijection seems more of a programming exercise than math.