# Natural bijection between $\mathbb{N}$ and algebraic numbers?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

> ***Q***. Is there a canonical, explicit bijection between the natural 
>   numbers $\mathbb{N}$ and the
>   [algebraic numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_number)?

The earlier MSE question, 
"[Bijection for algebraic numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/364775/237),"
does not quite answer the question.

Comment: Probably begin by enumerating the polynomials with integer coefficients, then go along to enumerate their roots.

Comment: There are different polynomials with integer coefficients having exactly the same roots, for example $x-1$ and $2x - 2$. So it will be difficult to make this canonical.

Comment: Canonical in what sense?

Comment: In terms of "explicit," it's probably difficult to even write an *explicit* enumeration of irreducible polynomials.

Comment: What do 'natural', 'canonical' and 'explicit' mean? (Not OP, just wondering)

Comment: @ThomasAndrews It's not so bad though – you could write a program (for an ideal computer with infinite memory) that enumerates all of them.

Comment: Sure, but usually "explicit" means something different from merely some recursive enumeration (although it is a loose term, like "closed form," which has no formal definition.) @ZhenLin

Comment: By "natural" or "canonical" I mean something akin to the bijection with rationals obtained via a zigzag walk through a 2-dimensional grid of reduced rationals, e.g., as explained *[here](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~mec/2008-2009/Bertiger/Lecture_3.html)*.

Comment: In that case, would you consider the enumeration of polynomials that I suggest to be "natural"?

Comment: @ZhenLin: I don't see your suggestion...? In any case, enumeration of the polynomials does not handle the fact that many polynomials have the same roots. So obtaining a bijection seems not straightforward.

Comment: The procedure is simple. Fix a well-ordering of polynomials with integer coefficients – to do that, you could take a well-ordering of the integers and use the lexicographic ordering. Then throw away all the ones that are not irreducible. This can all be done computably, maybe even primitive-recursively. Then if you really wanted to, you can numerically approximate the complex roots and then order them lexicographically.

Comment: @ZhenLin: Perhaps this is the best one can achieve. But it is not explicit, in the sense that you could not tell me which is, say, the 17th algebraic number. I am a bit skeptical of the step of ordering the roots.

Comment: I am not an expert in numerical analysis, but my understanding is that it is possible to find roots numerically to any given precision, so we just have to compute the set of roots sufficiently precisely. Infinite precision is _not_ required because each polynomial has finitely many roots.

Comment: Actually, I just noticed that lexicographic ordering does not give a well-ordering of polynomials. Instead we should order it first by (degree) + (magnitude of largest coefficient), then lexicographically. (Then we can also skip the step of choosing a well-ordering of the integers and use the standard linear order instead.)